# How can my program be prevented from freezing?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have decided to finally work on a project, as I've tried to code in python before, with at least some success. In my project, I am trying to build a menu that lets me "Auto-farm" in a game. It uses 3 modules, namely `pynput`, `pause`, and `PySimpleGUI`.

Whenever I run the code, it runs fine, until I click the button that starts the automation part. It runs completely fine, but I have to force close the GUI prompt that shows up as it just completely stops responding to input until you close it.

How I can make a stop button, and stop my program from freezing up?

I am using 2 files to keep this project slightly more organized, although I don't know if this is the best way to go around doing this. These 2 files are `main.py` and `chand.py`.

**main.py**

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import chand

loop = 0

layout = [[sg.Text("Welcome to RedGrowie's autofarm menu!")], [sg.Button("Chandeliers")]]

window = sg.Window("Autofarming Menu", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == "Chandeliers":
        loop = 1
        if loop == 1:
             chand.Chandeliers.start(self=chand.Chandeliers)



window.close
```

**chand.py**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import pause

keyboard = Controller()
start = "0"

class Chandeliers:
    def d_press(self):
        keyboard.press("d")
        pause.milliseconds(70)
        keyboard.release("d")
        pause.milliseconds(300)
        keyboard.release(Key.space)

    def space_press(self):
        keyboard.press(Key.space)
        pause.milliseconds(1)
        #keyboard.release(Key.space)

    def start(self):
        start = "1"
        while start == "1":
            self.d_press(self)
            self.space_press(self)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Chandeliers.start` function loops indefinitely, so the call from the main loop in `main.py` never gets returned to. If you want both loops to be running at the same time, you probably need to use `threading` or some other means of concurrency. Or you might be able to interleave the two loops somehow, depending on the timing requirements for each one.

As a side note, you are using your `Chandeliers` class in a very odd way. You're never creating an instance of the class, but rather calling the methods it defines as if they were class methods (but with manual passing of the class, in the misleadingly named `self` argument.

You should probably not do that. Either treat the class as a normal one, and create an instance:

```
cha = chand.Chandeliers()
cha.start() # and change start to not manually pass self any more
```

Or you should do away with the unneeded class all together and just make the methods into top-level functions.